# Почему не все элементы массива не выводятся на страницу?

Tags: javascript, dom, for

Условия таковы При нажатии .b-2 выполняете функцию. Функция перебирает массив a1 c помощью цикла for (let i. Выведите на страницу в .out-1 формате значение + пробел.

```js
let a1 = [1,3,4,5]
document.querySelector('.b-2').onclick = ()=>{
    for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        const element = array[i];
            document.querySelector('.p-2').textContent = element;
    console.log(element);
        }
}
```

```html
<button class="b-2">x</button>
 <p class="p-2"></p>
```

Comment: array is not defined - что тут вам не ясно?

Comment: А что такое array, где вы его определили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так поробуйте,
и обратите внимание на то что у Вас нет перемпенной `array`. Вы скопировали частично код при этом не поняв что и зачем.

```js
let a1 = [1,3,4,5]
document.querySelector('.b-2').onclick = ()=>{
    for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        const element = a1[i];
        document.querySelector('.p-2').textContent = element;
        console.log(element);
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="b-2">x</button>
 <p class="p-2"></p>
```

перепишите это немного по другому и станет более читабельнее

```js
let array = [1,3,4,5];
const paragraph = document.querySelector('.p-2');

document.querySelector('.b-2').onclick = ()=>{
    array.forEach((item, index)=>{
        paragraph.textContent +=' ' + item;
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

```html
<button class="b-2">x</button>
 <p class="p-2"></p>
```